# Regular Expression for finding sub string

Tags: regex

Is a regular expression the correct way of going about this?

I have a list of strings (Big Ape, Big Bird, Small Bird, Small Ape, Medium Ape, Silver Ape, Blue Ape, Black Ape) if I enter 'Big' the regular expression should return (Big Ape, Big Bird), if I enter 'al' the the list that is returned is 'Small Bird, Small Ape). Is this possible, kind of context search with regular expressions?

Comment: what language. how big of a list? is it in a database?

Comment: I was under the impression regular expression are kind of language agnostic. The list could be large, 2000+ items and its not in a database.

Comment: Regular Expressions are a "mini" programming language, that most "real" languages have support for in their library. 

The regex "pattern" specifies a "mini-program" that searches text. It is this pattern syntax that is pretty much the same across all the languages that use regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy, but RE's are more powerful than you need for simple substring matching.

Here is an example in python

```
import re   ### regular expression library

possibilities = ['Big Ape', 'Big Bird', 'Small Bird', 'Small Ape',
                 'Medium Ape', 'Silver Ape', 'Blue Ape', 'Black Ape']

def search(list, pattern):
    output = []
    for item in list:
       match = re.search(pattern, item)
       if match:
           output.append(item)
    return output
```

The output:

```
>>> search(possibilities, 'Big')
['Big Ape', 'Big Bird']

>>> search(possibilities, 'al')
['Small Bird', 'Small Ape']
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex could do that for you, yes. Depending on the programming language you are using a `.Contains("Big")` or something like that might be a more straightforward approach.

Comment: The language is Real Basic and I'm pretty sure it doesn't have such powerful functions built in. I believe this would need to be a match with the specified reg ex pattern. It the pattern I need help with.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible, regular expression can tell if a string match or not a pattern, eg:

does 'Big Ape' match /Big/ ? => yes
does 'Small Ape' match /Big/ ? => no
does 'Big Ape' match /al/ ? => no
does 'Small Ape' match /al/ ? => yes

almost any language let you use regular expression easily so you can probably do this.

but regular expressions are really usefull when working with more complexe pattern. In your case, your programmation language may provide simpler function for your problem. eg, in php:

does 'Big Ape' match /Big/ ? translate to `(strpos ('Big Ape', 'Big') !== false)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a regular expression is a great way to do this.

Here's a sample console application in C# that takes what you'd like to match as an argument; for example 'big' or 'al' as in the question. Internally, the argument is used as a regex to match against your sample inputs.

### Code

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
        // Inputs to try to match.
        string[] inputs = { "Big Ape", "Big Bird", "Small Bird", "Small Ape",
                            "Medium Ape", "Silver Ape", "Blue Ape", "Black Ape" };

        var stringToMatch = args[0];
        Regex regex = new Regex(stringToMatch, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // Container for all inputs that match the given regular expression.
        var matchList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var input in inputs)
        {
            Match parse = regex.Match(input);
            if (parse.Success)
            {
                matchList.Add(input);
                Console.WriteLine(input);
            }
        }
  }
```

### Output

> SampleApplication.exe al
>   Small Bird
>   Small Ape
>
> SampleApplication.exe big
>   Big Ape
>   Big Bird